# How to get a specific array from a list of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to get a specific array based on a code, the array is something like this:

```
const arr = [
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=11f18ac1-0476-4a1e-ada6-09e6566abc19",
    1595619171842,
    "0b7ad06f-7776-4bab-a8c6-53fd5fd5bd9b"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=b64c143d-e817-434f-bf6f-0bd0e8d9e7b5",
    1595619171844,
    "2f44a130-71d9-47ce-b5d5-04587c3c81fc"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=71dc5d26-75f4-4141-905e-074b0705eac4",
    1595619171845,
    "d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=d3645614-0ea3-4d17-80ab-57c6c6525fab",
    1595619171846,
    "940fb9a7-6fdd-4f8b-a808-26a9c60114bf"
  ]
];
```

How to I get the array with code "d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00"?
I was using reduce to get the more recent image, but now I have no idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) is best suited for this purpose.

```
const res = arr.find(([,,code])=>code==="d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00");
```

```js
const arr = [
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=11f18ac1-0476-4a1e-ada6-09e6566abc19",
    1595619171842,
    "0b7ad06f-7776-4bab-a8c6-53fd5fd5bd9b"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=b64c143d-e817-434f-bf6f-0bd0e8d9e7b5",
    1595619171844,
    "2f44a130-71d9-47ce-b5d5-04587c3c81fc"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=71dc5d26-75f4-4141-905e-074b0705eac4",
    1595619171845,
    "d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00"
  ],
  [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ziro-a…=media&token=d3645614-0ea3-4d17-80ab-57c6c6525fab",
    1595619171846,
    "940fb9a7-6fdd-4f8b-a808-26a9c60114bf"
  ]
];
const res = arr.find(([,,code])=>code==="d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first elmenent of an array that returns true for the given function.

```
const specificArray = arr.find(subArray => {
     return subArray[2] === "d7eb2a05-1f5a-48dd-b7ac-f3b071499d00";
}
```